# Operator showing true for all keys in for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm loading some data into the page and then iterating through it.  I only want certain keys visibly appended to the page.  (The others should be appended in hidden input.)  It seems like the if statement is checking to see if any key is true for any value in the object instead of just the particular key and value in the loop.  Anyway here is what is not working.

```
//example data
var yaml = {"title": "blog", "author": "John Doe", "layout": "blog.hbt", "url": "my-blog", "date": "10-2-2015"};

function addYaml(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (key == 'title'||'author'||'layout') {
            var type = 'text';
            var label = "<label>"+key+"</label>";
            $('#input').append(label+'<br />');
            }
            else{var type = 'hidden';}

            var input = "<input type='"+type+"' name='"+key+"' value='"+data[key]+"' />";
            $('#input').append(input+'<br />');
        }
    }

addYaml(yaml);
```

It appends everything (the hidden property is never applied).  No matter if the key is not 'title, author, or layout'.

Comment: **ANSWER:** `(key == 'title'||'author'||'layout') {` ==> `(key == 'title' || key == 'author' || key == 'layout') {`

Comment: Nonempty strings are always true, so `'author' => true`.

Comment: Its js...not a natural programming language :)

Comment: Open the console and view syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(key == 'title'||'author'||'layout')` is not valid for your case, it will always return `title` Logical OR is short-circuited and any non-empty string is truthy. So essentially what you are doing is `(key == 'title' || true)`. Change it to check individually.

```
if (key == 'title' || key == 'author' || key == 'layout') {
```

Comment: It is valid syntax, it just doesn't do what the user thinks it does.

Comment: I knew it was gonna be something stupid on my part.  (facepalm)

Comment: @TDave00 happens to everyone.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The latest edit is not valid, Check `'title'||'author'||'layout'` in console it returns first truthy value i.e. `title`

Comment: @Tushar, the edit is correct. If the key is not title, it will go to the true part.

Comment: @Tushar I think you are confusing `key == 'title'` with `'title'`, your last edit wasn't correct and changed the meaning of the answer, as `(key == 'title')` will not always be true. The `|| true` on the end is quite important.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use syntax like this:

```
// Near the top of the function
var targets = ["title", "author", "layout"];

// Later on:
if (targets.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
  // A valid target
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll put that one in my back pocket.  :)